# How do we know JSContext in Objective-C can do subscripting?

Tags: objective-c, webkit, javascriptcore

There are many example codes like this:

```
JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
        context[@"globalFunc"] =  ^() {
        NSArray *args = [JSContext currentArguments];
        for (id obj in args) {
            NSLog(@"got:%@", obj);
        }
    };
```

What confusing me is the `context[@"globalFunc"] = ***` statement . It looks like that JSContext is supporting subscripting (operator [ ])?

But I don't found any official documents say that ? So how do we know we can do subscripting in JSContext to set/get objects from it ?

Answer (score 0):

OK ,I miss the extension code just after JSContext's declaration -_-

```
@interface JSContext (SubscriptSupport)

/*!
@method
@abstract Get a particular property on the global object.
@result The JSValue for the global object's property.
*/
- (JSValue *)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;

/*!
@method
@abstract Set a particular property on the global object.
*/
- (void)setObject:(id)object forKeyedSubscript:(NSObject <NSCopying> *)key;

@end
```